# Does GTX 1650 encode/render videos at better speed/performance than RX 6500 XT?

Tags: graphics-cards, video-editing, rendering

I've heard a lot on YouTube reviews that 6500 XT is better than GTX 1650 but there's one bad thing about it. 6500 XT renders video at very slow speed especially in Premiere Pro (maybe rendering is done by CPU and not this GPU. I'm not sure how it works.)

So I can prefer 6500 XT any day for its better gaming. But I also have to render some videos. If there's significant difference between render times and 1650 render speed or video editing is better, I can sacrifice 6500 XT's extra FPS in gaming. I would choose 1650.

Given all that, is 1650 better in video editing and render speed as compared to 6500 XT? (Provided all other PC components are same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.guru3d.com/articles-pages/radeon-rx-6500-xt-review,23.html, the 6500XT is faster in OpenCL than the 1650 Super in Cuda. But if your video edit software only supports CUDA and not OpenCL, the 1650 is faster. Since Premire Pro supports both, I would reccomend getting the 6500XT, but make sure the render device is your graphics card since CPU's also support OpenCL.

Comment: 6500XT would work better in Blender? Because it has OpenCL

Comment: According to https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Render/Cycles/OpenCL, blender does not have OpenCL

Comment: Ah. It was removed in 3.0